# How to subscribe to a particular document and not only a collection in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to subscribe to the bookings of currentDate, so that I can get real time updates on the bookings. This is the structure:

`approvedBusinesses/docId/bookings/currentDate`

I can easily subscribe to a collection on Firestore.

```
const unsubscribeBookings = 
  firebase.firestore().collection('approvedBusinesses').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      const bookingsToday = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
    })
```

However, I can't subscribe to a single document or to a particular part of that document

```
const unsubscribeBookings = 
  firebase.firestore().collection('approvedBusinesses').doc(businessId).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
//the above won't work.
      const bookingsToday = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to listen to a document in a subcollection at a specific path "approvedBusinesses/docId/bookings/currentDate", then you will have to build a DocumentReference to that path.

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection('approvedBusinesses')
    .doc(businessId)
    .collection('bookings')
    .doc(currentDate)
```

Firestore listeners are **shallow** and do not consider documents in subcollections, so you can't listen to a parent document and get results from documents in subcollections.  You need to target the specific document in the subcollection.

Comment: ```snapshot.docs.map``` should still work in this case as well? I would still get real time updates?

Comment: You can get realtime updates from any document or query that could return multiple documents.